# iOS Screen gets stuck when switching to landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For the app, the orientation is in portrait most of the time, but we have one view that needs to be set to landscape.  I have this code to set it to landscape:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I also have device orientation set to portrait and landscape left in the general tab for the app.

The issue is that the app will sometimes work properly but other times it will get stuck in a mix between portrait and landscape.
I have provided an image of what it looks like getting [Stuck in transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faE8J.png).  If I then reload the view it will work properly, it is only on the first time opening the view that it has a chance of failing.

Comment: is this testeed on real device or only simulator?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani It is a real device and I've seen it happen more often on iPhones than on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set this in AppDelegate.m

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window {
    if self.rotatble {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape
    } else {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
    }
```